# Which is correct "not on war" "not in war"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

"We are not on war"

"We are not in war"

Answer (score 5):

I think that "We're not at war" is correct ([example](http://www.thisdaylive.com/index.php/2016/05/29/were-not-at-war-obaseki-admonishes-fellow-guber-aspirants/)).

Comment: I was going to post a comment showing results from Google Books for all three of *Britain was **at/on/in** war*. But for reasons I can't begin to understand, GB claims ***in*** is over 6 times more common that ***at*** there. (Fortunately, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+in+war+with%2Cwas+on+war+with%2Cwas+at+war+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20in%20war%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20at%20war%20with%3B%2Cc0) gets it right! :)